# Asset tag source

Tags: asset-management

can anyone recommend (or recommend to avoid) a source for asset labels?

id like foil, potentially with a color logo if possible.  so if youve had something like that printed before, please speak up.

google returns far too many results to be manageable.

Comment: Your physical location would be a good help to potential answerers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we ended up using mavericklabel.com

Answer (score 0):

My employer uses this place for ours: http://www.lustrecal.com/ we get foil stamped tags with our name on it and order many thousands a year.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Seton](http://www.seton.com/asset-id).  We also get the company name, and specify the starting number for each order.